# Alternative way to dynamically render React components coming from an API

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, switch-statement

I'm building a website with Next.js/React that is consuming content from Strapi CMS.

I want to keep a page template for a news article as flexible as possible, so content editors so they can choose what content they want to include.
Every post will contain certain items such as a title, date etc. But other sections are optional e.g.:

- Call to action
- Quote
- Aside panel

I have coded this with a map + switch statement to loop through the incoming data, adding components when necessary.

Next.js Page consuming API:

```
const Homepage = ({content, error}) => {
    return (
            <Layout>
                <h1>Hello World</h1>
                <Sections sections={content.sections}></Sections>
            </Layout>
        );
    }
}


export async function getServerSideProps() {
    const articleResponse = await fetcher(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRAPI_URL}/blogPost/whateverpost?populate=deep`);

        return {
            props: {
                content: articleResponse.data.attributes,
            }
        };
}

export default Homepage;
```

Example Next.js/React switch statement:

```
 const Sections = ({ sections }) => {
        return (
            <>
                {sections && sections.map((section) => {
                    switch (section.__component) {
                        case 'section.hero':
                            return (
                                <Hero hero={section}></Hero>
                            )
                            break;
                        case 'section.content-no-image':
                            return (
                                <ContentNoImage section={section}></ContentNoImage>
                            )
                            break;
                        case 'section.content-with-image':
                            return (
                                <ContentWithImage section={section}></ContentWithImage>
                            )
                            break;
                        case 'section.be-part-of-the-process':
                            return(
                                <BePartOfTheProcess section={section}></BePartOfTheProcess>
                            )
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                })}
            </>
        )
    }

export default Sections
```

What I'm unsure of is whether a map + switch statement the best way to do this? Is this old fashioned and is there a better way to do this in modern JavaScript/React(/Next)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks OK. Alternatively you can create object to be used with map:

```
const sectionComponents = {
  'section.hero': Hero,
  'section.content-no-image': ContentNoImage,
  'section.content-with-image': ContentWithImage,
  'section.be-part-of-the-process': BePartOfTheProcess,
};

const Sections = ({ sections }) => (
  <>
    {sections?.map((section) => {
      const SectionComponent = sectionComponents[section.__component];
      return SectionComponent ? <SectionComponent section={section} /> : null;
    })}
  </>
);
```